# Remove values from existing XML

Tags: php, arrays, xml, object

Consider XMLsample with having values in and I want to remove the values and display or store the XMLfile with only tags and attributes if any, not with any values in elements
example:

`<hello> hi how </hello>` convert this to `<hello></hello>` and my XML is having 2 or 3 depth child elements also

Comment: sample is :  ```<hello> greetings </hello> to <hello></hello>

Comment: Title and question do not really match. Do you want to create XML with empty values or remove values from existing XML?

Comment: He wants to remove values. @ÁlvaroGonzález

Comment: yes i want to remove values from existing xml

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42600811/replace-all-characters-in-a-string-that-are-between-two-other-characters-in-java/42600905#42600905

Comment: i want to empty the values not tags

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string); 
ClearRecurse($xml); 
echo $xml->asXML();

function ClearRecurse(&$xml) 
{ 
   $children = $xml->children();
   if (empty($children)) {
     $xml[0] = "";                   // No child - clear value
   }
   else {
     foreach($xml->children() as $key=>$value) {
        ClearRecurse($value);        // Repeat for all descendants
      }     
   } 
}
```

**[demo on eval.in](https://eval.in/773225)**

Comment: my xml also contains comments

Comment: Do you want to empty it too ?

Comment: Comment is not tag value

Comment: sorry i want to remove comments also ..only want to keep the tags and attributes if present

Comment: after removing comments still not working with ur code